# Favicon has white rather than transparent background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A minor point, but the new favicon (coffee cup) has a white rather than transparent background - unlike the other sites:

[image]

Can we have a nice transparent background please?

Comment: i'll put out the transparent version today.

Comment: @Jin Thanks. Post an answer so I can accept it as well as tagging the question `[status-complete]`.

Comment: I was thinking `[status-by-design]`, but now that I've checked, it would look better on the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transparent versions of the favicons(parent site and Meta) will be in the next deployment.

Comment: If only I could get Chrome to refresh them when *I* wanted to, not when it decided it would ;)

Comment: @ChrisF It is on production now. You may have to manually refresh it, or wait when Chrome is in the mood to. http://sstatic.net/programmersmeta/img/favicon.ico